# How to call two onClick events from different places

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a button that is going to have a onClick that is hardcoded and another one that however uses the component, can create his custom onClick. I don't believe this is a duplicated since all the questions i was able to found advise to use both onClick's in a hardcoded way, that can't be changed when using the Button component.

This the component:

```
const Button = props => {
  const { children, toggle, ...other } = props;
  const [pressed, setPressed] = useState(true);
  const renderPressedButton = e => {
    setPressed(!pressed);
    onClick(); //here onClick should be called
  };
  return (
    <StyledButton
      toggle={toggle}
      pressed={toggle ? pressed : null}
      onClick={toggle && renderPressedButton}
      {...other}>
      {children}
    </StyledButton>
  );
};
```

I have also tried this function on the onClick event:

```
const onClickHandler = () => {
   renderPressedButton();
   onClick();
}
```

And using the component i would have my custom onClick

```
    const anotherClickHandler = () => {
         console.log('Hey, this is a function outside Button component');
    }

<Button onClick={anotherClickHandler}>Button</Button>
```

What i have tried is calling the `onClick();` inside the `renderPressedButton` from the first onClick but it did not work. The second onClick(`anotherClickHandler`) is called but not the first one(`renderPressedButton`).

What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution.

On the main Button:

```
const Button = props => {
  const { onClick } = props; //first i add onClick as a prop
  const [pressed, setPressed] = useState(true);
  const renderPressedButton = () => {
    setPressed(!pressed);
    if (onClick) {//then i check, if theres an onClick, execute it
      onClick();
    }
  };
  return (
    <StyledButton
      pressed={pressed}
      {...props}
      onClick={renderPressedButton}
    />
  );
};
```

And when using the Button:

```
<Button onClick={justASimpleOnClickHandler}>Toggle</Button>
```

This way i can have my main onClick function and another one when using my component.